# Не меняется значения переменной boolean

Tags: java, swing

Решил написать блокнотик. Дошёл до функции... автосохранения? я хз как она называется... решил сделать проверку через булеан. Но он не изменяется! ЧЯДНТ? в главном классе я просто запускаю функцию saveFile.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Page{


boolean isSaved;
private String path = "";
private File file;

public Page(){
   isSaved = false ;
}

public void saveFile(JTabbedPane tabs){

if(!isSaved){
  isSaved = true;
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
  fc.showSaveDialog(null);
  file = fc.getSelectedFile();
  path = file.getAbsolutePath();
  Scroll s = (Scroll)tabs.getSelectedComponent();
  try{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    fw.write(s.getText()); 
    fw.close();
  }catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
  isSaved = true;

}else{
  Scroll s = (Scroll)tabs.getSelectedComponent();
  try{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    fw.write(s.getText()); 
    fw.close();
  }catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
}
}
}
```

Comment: А как ты проверяешь значение?

Comment: @НиколайБеляков if(!isSaved)...

Comment: Я так понял, значение у тебя не меняется после выполнения метода. А ты мне показываешь как в начале метода проверяешь.

Comment: @НиколайБеляков смотри, сразу после проверки if(!isSaved) я присваиваю ей значение.

Comment: Присвоил true, молодец. В чем тогда трудность?

Comment: так оно не изменяется при выполнении программы!

Comment: А как именно вы проверяете изменилось оно или нет?)))

Comment: @НиколайБеляков у меня оно не меняется при выполнении программы!

Comment: Так я тебя и спросил как ты это узнал что оно не изменяется?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,isSaved);

Comment: Почему меня терзают смутные сомненья что таки область видимости замешана в этом странном поведении =) Откуда вызывается приведенный вами код?)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков из класса, где и инициализируется графика.

Comment: Перечитайте мой комментарий и подумайте над первым предложением примерно до тех пор, пока не поймете о чем я говорю.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков что-то я не врубаюсь... ну сказали вы что от окружения не зависит, и что?

Comment: Вы точно мое сообщение перечитывали? я про окружение ни слова не сказал. **Почему меня терзают смутные сомненья что таки область видимости замешана в этом странном поведении** внутри класса вы работаете с переменной обьявленной внутри этого класса, и ее значение доступно только внутри класса(или через ссылку на класс) а вы пытаетесь ее выводить по имени, находясь вне класса, и само собой работаете не с этой переменной.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков а окружение и область видимости не одно и тоже? Ну и куда что вы предлагаете сделать?

Comment: А с чего вы решили что она вне класса?

Comment: @GENKY не поверите, но нет, не одно и тоже =) `А с чего вы решили что она вне класса?` может быть потому что я спросил у вас **Откуда вызывается приведенный вами код**

Comment: @Владимир Клыков я вам ответил. Из другого класса в ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что я постоянно создавал обьект Page, и почему-то и из-за этого не работало.